# How to retrieve data through model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have `Order` model with another relation `OrderPhoto`:

```php
public function OrderPhoto()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\OrderPhoto');
}
```

In turn `OrderPhoto` model has relation:

```php
public function Photo()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Photo');
}
```

So, how to get data from `OrderModel` with related data from third model `Photo`?

I guess this:

```php
Order::with("OrderPhoto.Photo")->get();
```

to retrieve only data from `Photo` model for each `Order`

So, each `Order` has some `OrderPhotos`. Relationship is one to many.

But one item from `OrderPhotos` is related with primary key from table `Photos`. It is one to one relation.

My result query should be:

```php
select `photos`.*, `ordersphoto`.`Orders_Id` from `photos` inner join `ordersphoto` on `ordersphoto`.`Photos_Id` = `photos`.`Id` where `ordersphoto`.`Orders_Id` in (1);
```

How to use `hasManyThrough` for this query?

Comment: Is OrderPhoto-Photo really a many-to-many relationship? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You can use `with` to get related tables in the query. Have a look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Order::with('related_table_name')->get();

Comment: I need to connect with model through another model

Comment: Seems like order photo should an intermediate table between photos and orders.  Doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: @OPV provide a sample of data in the four (?) tables and your desired output.

Comment: See my explanation about relations between tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just having a quick look at your relationships it looks like you could create a hasManyThrough relationship on the order Model.

```
public function Photo {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\OrderPhoto', 'App\Photo')
}
```

You may need to add the table keys to make it work

This will allow you to do:

```
Order::with("Photo")->get();
```

You can see more details here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

**Update**

Try this

```
public function Photo {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Photo', 'App\OrderPhoto', 'Order_id', 'Photos_id', 'id', 'id')
}
```

It is a little hard to get my head around your DB structure with this info but you should hopefully be able to work it out. This may also help

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.html#method_hasManyThrough

Comment: Can you help with keys in `hasManyThrough`?

Comment: In my case `OrderPhoto` is intermediate table

Comment: I added query to question

Comment: For me work this: `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Photo', 'App\OrderPhoto', 'Photos_Id' , 'Id', 'Id', 'Orders_Id');` I it correct?

Comment: try running it and if you get the results that you are after it is working otherwise it will normally either through an error or send back an empty collection